# Head First C (geo2jason tool)

Tags: c

Below is the program from Head First C. I failed to understand  the purpose of the  variable `started` and why it was used with if statement:

```
if (started)
    printf(",\n");
else
    started = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    char info[80];
    int started = 0;

    puts("data=[");
    while (scanf("%f,%f,%79[^\n]", &latitude , &longitude , info ) == 3) {
        if (started)
            printf(",\n");
        else
            started = 1 ;
        if ((latitude < -90.0) || (latitude >90.0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid latitude: %f\n",  latitude);
            return 2;
        }
        if ((longitude < -180.0) || (longitude > 180.0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid longitude: %f\n",  longitude);
            return 2;
        }

        printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f , info: '%s'}", latitude , longitude , info );
     }
     puts("\n]");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this was taken from a book, you need a new book. Comparing a `float` variable with double constants such as `90.0` is conceptually wrong and bad. Also, using if-else without braces { } ("compound statement") is dangerous style and shouldn't be taught. And also minor nit-pick: `int main()` is obsolete function declaration style - books shouldn't teach obsolete style.

Comment: @Lundin: Your `float` point is an important one, but scientific programmers know that floating point schemes are capable of holding whole numbers exactly.

Comment: Thanks . Please suggest a good book

Comment: started is used to print the newline after each iteration of while loop

Comment: K&R͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Oh btw the book is also bad for teaching you to use `int` for boolean types. That's 1980s style C programming. Use `bool` or `_Bool` instead.

Comment: @Lundin Can you please suggest a good book for starters?

Comment: It's there to distinguish between first and following lines. If you want to separate lines with ",\n" you need to know that there is (at last) one line already. This is why you have started variable.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even if the floating point standard of the given system were able to represent the result of a `double` calculation in `float` format without introducing oddities, it is still bad, because the code forces the compiler to perform the calculation on a larger type than what's necessary. I very much doubt the compiler can optimize the calculation down to `float`, because in order to do so it must prove internally that the result would be identical.

Comment: @Beeran: As Bathsheba already said: [The C Programming Language by the developers of C: K&R](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628).

Comment: @Beeran Sorry, I have no idea if any good beginner-level books even exist for C. I can just make anti-recommendations. Avoid K&R like the plague, for example. We do have a book recommendation page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list but it is full of good books mixed with crap books.

Comment: @Andre Thanks a lot. Initially I googled K&R . but got nothing. your suggestion worked. Thanks

Comment: @Lundin: What's wrong about K&R, too old?

Comment: @Lundin: This odd fish here thinks that K&R ought to be accepted into the biblical canon, but I will concede that you are more of a C expert than I.

Comment: There's plenty I could say about K&R, few things good, but let's not derail this comment field with book discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is because there is no such a `boolean` type in the C language...

so you can do emulate any "boolean" variable, where 0 means false and any other value is considered true

so the block

```
if (started) { .... }
```

will only be executed when ***started*** is different from 0

Comment: Thanks for explaining in laymen language

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather long-winded way of circumventing an initial print of a comma followed by a newline, that's all.

I prefer using a `for` loop for this kind of thing in order to keep the variable in a tighter scope:

```
for (
    int started = 0;
    scanf("%f,%f,%79[^\n]", &latitude , &longitude , info ) == 3;
    started = 1
){
```

Comment: That's about as messy as the original code. Less obscure version: `printf(",\n"); int result = 0; while(result!=3) { result = scanf(...); ... }`. do-while would also be fine.

Comment: @Lundin: Perhaps I'm just an odd fish but I find my suggestion crystal clear.

Comment: You are an odd fish! :) If you look at the original code again, the `started` variable isn't even needed, it is just ugly clutter.